# Chunks cannot be downloaded because session expired

Tags: angular

Our server is behind reverse proxy and when session expires every request is redirected to login page.

The problem occurs when user click somewhere and angular needs to fetch another chunk. This request is redirected via 302 html code to login page. Angular follows redirection, downloads this login page and then fail because there are no chunk related data.

Is there a way to intercept this behavior and reload whole page in case this happens?  We are not able to change server configuration or structure in any way.

Comment: Maybe, single bundling would help.

Comment: Definitely, but similar issue is with regular ajax requests for data. I think there must be a place where I can register some logic around ajax calls, but cant find anything.